# How do I get the 'Filepath' attribute from a sound strip in the VSE?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

How do I get the `filepath` attribute from a sound strip of a video sequence ? I am talking about the sound strip that comes with a video file.

**Sound strip : demo.001**   `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["demo.001"].filepath`

==> 'SoundSequence' object has no attribute 'filepath'

I *can* get the `filepath` from the associated video strip.

**Video strip : demo.avi**   `bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["demo.avi"].filepath`

==> this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the `sound` property of that strip which has the `filepath` property:

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["demo.001"].sound.filepath
```

Comment: Thanks Ray ! It works ! How did u know ??

Comment: Values in the api are more often than not, represented in the UI as well, which may give hints as to where it might be in the UI. In this case, the filepath in the UI is listed as a property of a `sound` object (looking at its python tooltip), so I then looked for a sound property on the sequence strip.

Comment: Clever... well, thanks again ! I learnt two things today :-)